# Query in a recursive Many to Many relationship with a Through table, Django

Tags: django, django-models

My models.py is:

```
User(models.Model):
  people = models.ManyToManyField('self', through='Friend', symmetrical=False)

Friend(models.Model):
  from_user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='friends')
  to_user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='friends_of')
  accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

To get a queryset of `User` instance of all `Friend` objects related to `user_instance`, I'm currently doing something like:

```
user_instance.people.all() | user_instance.user_set.all()
```

This works, but what I want is that of  `accepted = True` only. Something like:

```
user_instance.people.filter(people__accepted=True) | user_instance.user_set.filter(people__accepted=True)
```

Note: Renamed friendship to people

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to see if `user_instance.friendship.filter(friendship__accepted=True)` works? I think that's the proper way to do it. Documentation here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Also I'd recommend you rename friendship to friends or friendships, it might get you confused in the future, since it can be many friends

Comment: Thanks Mojimi for the link and for the suggestion. I've renamed the model☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
user_instance.people.filter(friends_of__accepted=True) | user_instance.user_set.filter(friends__accepted=True)
```

The point is, `related_name` should be prepended to `__accepted` instead of the field name `people`.